# How to use easily svg as icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I don't understand the "usefulness" of svg as it is not easily modifiable with CSS or Jquery.
For example:

```
<object data="../headset.svg" width="30" height="25" type="image/svg+xml" class="svg svg-danger" id="mysvg">
```

Great I can decide the size but the the fill color. I want to reuse this svg multiple time inside the document.

With:
    var a=document.getElementById("mysvg").contentDocument;

I just get undefined.

The inside svg, that I don't want to hard code in my document:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 361.014 361.014" style="enable-background:new 0 0 361.014 361.014;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<g id="Layer_5_47_">
<path d="M331.035,126.94H318.01c-3.563,0-3.682-2.333-3.805-3.494C307.375,59.094,252.77,8.791,186.637,8.791h-12.26    c-65.644,0-119.929,49.56-127.409,113.229c-0.191,1.631-0.291,4.92-3.291,4.92H29.978C20.987,126.94,0,136.401,0,184.18v25.075    c0,35.436,20.987,43.609,29.978,43.609h43.584c8.991,0,16.347-7.356,16.347-16.347v-93.23c0-8.991-7.356-16.347-16.347-16.347    c0,0-2.052-0.18-1.529-3.835c7.192-50.319,50.129-89.313,102.344-89.313h12.26c51.86,0,94.912,38.418,102.2,88.288    c0.235,1.608,1.111,4.86-1.385,4.86c-8.991,0-16.347,7.356-16.347,16.347v93.23c0,8.991,7.356,16.347,16.347,16.347h8.184    c2.25,0,1.868,1.798,1.667,2.704c-6.667,30.104-21.637,64.256-55.238,64.256h-24.889c-2.54,0-3.167-1.861-3.65-2.743    c-4.032-7.367-11.851-12.364-20.841-12.364h-22.933c-13.118,0-23.753,10.634-23.753,23.753c0,13.119,10.635,23.752,23.753,23.752    h22.933c9.112,0,17.023-5.132,21.005-12.662c0.348-0.658,0.633-2.026,3.321-2.026h25.054c22.823,0,53.365-11.341,69.259-65.373    c1.694-5.758,3.068-11.496,4.187-17.026c0.154-0.761,0.25-2.27,2.625-2.27h12.9c8.991,0,29.978-8.174,29.978-43.609v-25.075    C361.013,137.082,340.026,126.94,331.035,126.94z" />
    </g>
</g>

</svg>
```

1/ How can I color it in red with jquery or orange? I just don't get it.
2/ Why svg is not easier to use?
Thanks,

Stef.

Comment: You can actually use the `<svg>` element directly these days and not embed it using an `<object>` You will, however, have to repeat the object for every instance you need it as CSS only applies to actual existing tags in the page. Once you included them as actual `<svg>` elements you can color and animate them using CSS easily (by targeting, like `svg [fill]{ fill: red; }` - You could use javascript to get a single element (you can even load them in using AJAX as they're just `html` strings) and then duplicate it everywhere you need it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to repeat the svg as it is a pain to maintain. Am I wrong?

Comment: The trade off is that you need to do it like this. However, I have used placeholders before, you could try something like `<img src="placeholder.gif" data-svg="svg.svg" />` and then load `svg.svg` with ajax and replace every `image[data-svg]` element with that loaded `svg` element. The only way to dynamically color SVGs with CSS, however, is to have the svg as an actual tag.

Comment: are you running document.getElementById("mysvg").contentDocument after the object tag load event?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado please read the question. i don't want to copy paste the svg inside my document.

Comment: @RobertLongson : in the console directly.

Comment: I have added an answer that will hopefully kill two birds with one stone - minimise copied code, keep your code separate and still allow all the SVG features...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need the `svg` to be embedded as an actual SVG so your CSS applies to it, you could use a little utility script like this:

```
function replaceSVGS(elements){
    if(!document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image", "1.1")) return;
    elements.forEach(function(e){
        var src = e.getAttribute('data-svg');
        if(!src) return;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
        request.addEventListener("load", function(){
            var a = document.createElement('div');
            a.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            a = a.querySelector('svg');
            e.parentNode.insertBefore(a, e);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        });
        request.open("GET", src);
        request.send();
    });
}
```

The script above will replace the elements with svg as long as they have `data-svg` - I would recommend using it like this:

```
replaceSVGS( Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-svg]')) );
```

Now you don't have to copy paste the code at all, and this script will ensure SVGs are inserted where appropriate. You just need an element with `data-svg`:

```
<img src="test.jpg" data-svg="test.svg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the SVG in CSS instead, you can compile it here (without base64 and with the mime type image/svg+xml: http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php

Then add a red fill path in the SVG, and create a ".red" CSS class that is reusable.

It's not ideal, but it's better than putting the svg code on the page itself.

```css
.mysvg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Capa_1%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20361.014%20361.014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%20361.014%20361.014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cg%3E%0D%0A%3Cg%20id%3D%22Layer_5_47_%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M331.035%2C126.94H318.01c-3.563%2C0-3.682-2.333-3.805-3.494C307.375%2C59.094%2C252.77%2C8.791%2C186.637%2C8.791h-12.26%20%20%20%20c-65.644%2C0-119.929%2C49.56-127.409%2C113.229c-0.191%2C1.631-0.291%2C4.92-3.291%2C4.92H29.978C20.987%2C126.94%2C0%2C136.401%2C0%2C184.18v25.075%20%20%20%20c0%2C35.436%2C20.987%2C43.609%2C29.978%2C43.609h43.584c8.991%2C0%2C16.347-7.356%2C16.347-16.347v-93.23c0-8.991-7.356-16.347-16.347-16.347%20%20%20%20c0%2C0-2.052-0.18-1.529-3.835c7.192-50.319%2C50.129-89.313%2C102.344-89.313h12.26c51.86%2C0%2C94.912%2C38.418%2C102.2%2C88.288%20%20%20%20c0.235%2C1.608%2C1.111%2C4.86-1.385%2C4.86c-8.991%2C0-16.347%2C7.356-16.347%2C16.347v93.23c0%2C8.991%2C7.356%2C16.347%2C16.347%2C16.347h8.184%20%20%20%20c2.25%2C0%2C1.868%2C1.798%2C1.667%2C2.704c-6.667%2C30.104-21.637%2C64.256-55.238%2C64.256h-24.889c-2.54%2C0-3.167-1.861-3.65-2.743%20%20%20%20c-4.032-7.367-11.851-12.364-20.841-12.364h-22.933c-13.118%2C0-23.753%2C10.634-23.753%2C23.753c0%2C13.119%2C10.635%2C23.752%2C23.753%2C23.752%20%20%20%20h22.933c9.112%2C0%2C17.023-5.132%2C21.005-12.662c0.348-0.658%2C0.633-2.026%2C3.321-2.026h25.054c22.823%2C0%2C53.365-11.341%2C69.259-65.373%20%20%20%20c1.694-5.758%2C3.068-11.496%2C4.187-17.026c0.154-0.761%2C0.25-2.27%2C2.625-2.27h12.9c8.991%2C0%2C29.978-8.174%2C29.978-43.609v-25.075%20%20%20%20C361.013%2C137.082%2C340.026%2C126.94%2C331.035%2C126.94z%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fg%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fg%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.mysvg.red {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Capa_1%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20361.014%20361.014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%20361.014%20361.014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cg%3E%0D%0A%3Cg%20id%3D%22Layer_5_47_%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22red%22%20d%3D%22M331.035%2C126.94H318.01c-3.563%2C0-3.682-2.333-3.805-3.494C307.375%2C59.094%2C252.77%2C8.791%2C186.637%2C8.791h-12.26%20%20%20%20c-65.644%2C0-119.929%2C49.56-127.409%2C113.229c-0.191%2C1.631-0.291%2C4.92-3.291%2C4.92H29.978C20.987%2C126.94%2C0%2C136.401%2C0%2C184.18v25.075%20%20%20%20c0%2C35.436%2C20.987%2C43.609%2C29.978%2C43.609h43.584c8.991%2C0%2C16.347-7.356%2C16.347-16.347v-93.23c0-8.991-7.356-16.347-16.347-16.347%20%20%20%20c0%2C0-2.052-0.18-1.529-3.835c7.192-50.319%2C50.129-89.313%2C102.344-89.313h12.26c51.86%2C0%2C94.912%2C38.418%2C102.2%2C88.288%20%20%20%20c0.235%2C1.608%2C1.111%2C4.86-1.385%2C4.86c-8.991%2C0-16.347%2C7.356-16.347%2C16.347v93.23c0%2C8.991%2C7.356%2C16.347%2C16.347%2C16.347h8.184%20%20%20%20c2.25%2C0%2C1.868%2C1.798%2C1.667%2C2.704c-6.667%2C30.104-21.637%2C64.256-55.238%2C64.256h-24.889c-2.54%2C0-3.167-1.861-3.65-2.743%20%20%20%20c-4.032-7.367-11.851-12.364-20.841-12.364h-22.933c-13.118%2C0-23.753%2C10.634-23.753%2C23.753c0%2C13.119%2C10.635%2C23.752%2C23.753%2C23.752%20%20%20%20h22.933c9.112%2C0%2C17.023-5.132%2C21.005-12.662c0.348-0.658%2C0.633-2.026%2C3.321-2.026h25.054c22.823%2C0%2C53.365-11.341%2C69.259-65.373%20%20%20%20c1.694-5.758%2C3.068-11.496%2C4.187-17.026c0.154-0.761%2C0.25-2.27%2C2.625-2.27h12.9c8.991%2C0%2C29.978-8.174%2C29.978-43.609v-25.075%20%20%20%20C361.013%2C137.082%2C340.026%2C126.94%2C331.035%2C126.94z%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fg%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fg%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E");  
}
```

```html
<div class="mysvg"></div>
<div class="mysvg red"></div>
```

Comment: This is okay, but it really hampers the reuseability of your code and it outputs a lot of duplicates... I use these, but only for one-ioffs...

Comment: For maintenance it's best to use PostCSS with PostCSS Assets plugin in gulp, then you can achieve inline(path-to-svg.svg), and keep the svg file where it is on the server/client. But that's completely overcomplicated for what the OP wants :D

Comment: Thats true, but it will still mean the SVG string is repeated several times in your CSS, which increases the CSS file size quite a lot. Again, if theres not much duplication this is fine. Also, these SVG's are not allowed to be animated etc... So it is more useful to actually have them in your page.

Comment: I would say my solution is fine for 2 colours, but if we are using random colours or an array of colours, a JS based solution would be more appropriate that adds the SVG to the page itself.